# How to prevent malicious costly querying on cloud platforms?

Tags: security, ddos, rate-limiting

Assume the Joker is a maximally sophisticated, well-equipped and malicious user of Batman's start up `batmanrules.com` hosted by, say, AWS infrastructure. The business logic of batmanrules.com requires that unregistered users be able to send http requests to the REST API layer of batman.com, which lead to the invocation (in one way or another) of queries against an AWS-based DB. Batman doesn't want to be constrained by DB type (it can be either SQL or noSQL).

The Joker wants to ruin batman **financially** by sending as many http requests as he can in order to run up Batman's AWS bill. The Joker uses all the latest tricks in the book using DDOS-like methods to send http requests from different IP addresses that target all sorts of mechanisms within batman.com's business logic.

**Main Question**: *how does Batman prevent financial ruin while keeping his service running smoothly for his normal users?*

Assume a lot of traffic is going on, how can you weed out the 'malicious' queries from the non-malicious, especially when users arent being registered? I know you can do rate-limiting against IP addresses, but cant the Joker (who is maximally sophisticated and well-equipped) find clever ways to issue requests from ever-changing IP addresses, and or to tweak the requests so that no two are exactly the same?

Note: my question focuses not on denial of service -- let's assume it's ok if the site goes down for a while -- but, rather, on Batman's financial loss. Batman has done a great job on making the architecture scale up and down with varying load, his only concern is that high loads (induced by Joker's shenanigans) entail high cost.

My instinct tells me that there is no silver bullet here, and that batman would have to build safeguards into his business logic (e.g. shut down if traffic spikes within certain parameters) AND/OR to require reCAPTCHA tokens on all non-trivial requests submitted to the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS WAF and configure rules to block malicious users.

For example a straight forward rule would be to do a rate base blocking where if you could find its highly unlikely to get above X amount of requests concurrently from a same IP address.

For advanced use cases you can implement custom rules by analyzing the request logs with Lambda and to apply the block in WAF.

In addition, as you clearly identified it is not possible to prevent all the malicious requests. The goal should be to inspect and prevent which is an ongoing process with the right architecture in place to block requests on need basis.